# ASP.NET Membership assigning Multiple Roles

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

I am trying to to assign a newly created user to the role 'Player.' I have 2 roles in total, 'Player' and 'Admin.'

When I do the following code, the newly created user is being assigned both roles, and not just the 'Player' role.

```
        string username = UserNameTextBox.ToString();
        Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "Player");
```

I can't understand why it's doing this, by removing the code it doesn't assign either roles to the user so i'm not sure why it's adding the 'Admin' role also.

Can anyone tell me why it's doing this? And how to make it so that only the player role is assigned?

Comment: This is really unusual. Are you sure you have "Player" role(Check case-sensitivity maybe). Also, can you provide your membership initialization code?

Comment: Checked case sensitivity, that's fine. And both Admin and Player roles exist. What code do you want to see?

Comment: How do you check that user is in both roles?